# Full-text search on column for existence of a keyword from a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I have a table of keywords and I want to query another table and return rows where a column contains at least one keyword.

Is it possible query like that using full text indexes?

If not is there a more efficient way than the one below - dynamic SQL perhaps?

```
SELECT
    *

FROM
    dbo.Notes AS NotesContainingKeyword

WHERE
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            *

        FROM
            dbo.Notes
            CROSS JOIN dbo.Keywords

        WHERE
            Notes.Note LIKE '%' + Keywords.Word '%'
            AND Notes.Id = NotesContainingKeyword.Id
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenating the keywords with an `OR(|)` separator into a variable appears to work.

```
DECLARE
    @Keywords NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT
    @Keywords = STUFF((
                    SELECT
                        '|' + Word

                    FROM
                        dbo.Keywords

                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '')

SELECT
    *

FROM
    dbo.Notes

WHERE
    CONTAINS(Note, @Keywords)
```